# How does (Float value + Integer value + long value) gives unexpected result?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Float f=new Float(3.1);
                Integer i=new Integer(1);
                long l=2;
                System.out.println("Result is "+l+f+i);
    }
}
```

Output : `Result is 23.11`

I saw the above code somewhere. I tried to find the reason behind such an unexpected output but no success. Please give some links or reference or explanation.

**Additional Information:** `System.out.println(l+f+i+" is Result");` gives `6.1 is Result`. That means order of string and numbers has effect on output.

Comment: You are printing the numbers instead to add them, it's actually quite a funny trap.

Comment: `System.out.println("Result is "+(l+f+i))`

Comment: And please *never* use `new Float(3.1)` and `new Integer(1)` unless you want to confuse whoever happens to read your code.

Comment: ohh @rilent ... now I can see that trap. thanks you..

Comment: @RDR Feel free to accept an answer now that the response has been provided, so the question can be marked as "answered" ;)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Nathan I was going to do that but ALL answers were 'satisfying answers' so I didn't do that. But now I have done it. :)

Comment: @RDR In these cases, you can either choose the "most elaborate answer", or you just accept the oldest one :) Glab we could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding an important point to the other answers here:**

Whenever you do String concatenation, the `toString()` method is called for each elements in the concatenation. So, your elements to be concatenated are,

```
"Result is ", l, f, and i
```

For, primitives, Autoboxing would first convert them to Wrapper classes and `toString()` method of each would be called and that's what happened.

Answer (score 4):

This is `String` concatenation,

```
System.out.println("Result is "+l+f+i);
```

Gives

```
System.out.println("Result is "+"2"+"3.1"+"1");
```

Better group your arithmetic computation :

```
System.out.println("Result is "+(l+f+i));
```

You may find more details here : [String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the number, you're printing them, because the default operation when placing an object in a `System.out.println` is to call his `toString()` method. So you're printing `l.toString() + f.toString() + i.toString()`.

if you want to display the sum, you have to use:

```
Float f=new Float(3.1);
Integer i=new Integer(1);
long l=2;
System.out.println("Result is "+ (l+f+i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating a String with any number primitives or objects convert them to String with their `toString()` method :

```
System.out.println("Result is "+l+f+i);
```

To perform the computation before the string concatenation, you should put the computation expression between parenthesis :

```
 System.out.println("Result is " + (l+f+i));
```